# How do I list jobs in Oracle dbms_scheduler?

Tags: oracle, dbms-scheduler

How do I list jobs created with Oracle `dbms_scheduler.create(...)`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT owner, job_name, comments FROM dba_scheduler_jobs;
```

There are many other columns of interest as well.